# Append correct numbers and letters to chess board created by DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a chess board using DOM. JS code is attached.
What I am trying to figure out now is how to append the numbers and letters to the appropriate tiles. Any ideas how I can achieve that?
One of my beginner ideas is to choose every table element and append a number/letter manually.

```
// Create a center tag to center all the elements
var center = document.createElement('center');
 
// Create a table element
var ChessTable = document.createElement('table');
for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    // Create a row
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

        // Create a cell
        var td = document.createElement('td');

        // If the sum of cell coordinates is even
        // then color the cell white
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {

            // Create a class attribute for all white cells
            td.setAttribute('class', 'cell whitecell');
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }

        // If the sum of cell coordinates is odd then
        // color the cell black
        else {

            // Create a class attribute for all black cells
            td.setAttribute('class', 'cell blackcell');

            // Append the cell to its row
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }

    // Append the row
    ChessTable.appendChild(tr);
}
center.appendChild(ChessTable);

// Modifying table attribute properties
ChessTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
ChessTable.setAttribute('width', '270px');
document.body.appendChild(center);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `<center>` tag, it is deprecated. If you need to center an element there are other ways of doing this (*such as using auto margins, using a flexbox or grid layout*).

As for the location names, you can set these when you append the `td` element. You can create an array to map the column number `j` to letters, and you already have a variable for the row numbers `i`.

```js
const columnMap = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

// Create a div container to center all the elements
const center = document.createElement('div');

// Create a table element
const ChessTable = document.createElement('table');

for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  // Create a row
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for(let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    // Create a cell
    const td = document.createElement('td');

    // If the sum of cell coordinates is even
    // then color the cell white
    if((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
      // Create a class attribute for all white cells
      td.setAttribute('class', 'cell whitecell');
    }
    // If the sum of cell coordinates is odd then
    // color the cell black
    else {
      // Create a class attribute for all black cells
      td.setAttribute('class', 'cell blackcell');
    }
    
    // Set the cell location text
    td.innerText = `${columnMap[j]}${8-i}`;

    // Append the cell
    tr.append(td);
  }

  // Append the row
  ChessTable.append(tr);
}
center.append(ChessTable);

// Modifying table attribute properties
ChessTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
ChessTable.setAttribute('width', '270px');

// You can center the table with 'auto' left and right margins
//ChessTable.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 0 auto;');

// Or by using a flexbox container
center.setAttribute('style', 'height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;');

document.body.append(center);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cell {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33.5px;
  height: 33.5px;
}
.whitecell { color: #000; background: #FFF; }
.blackcell { color: #FFF; background: #000; }
```